# CakePHP 3 Controller Event Implementation Example

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

The CakePHP 3.0 documentation includes an example of how to create an event using a model as an example. I've tried and tried and it's just not translating for me.  Does anyone have a CakePHP 3.x example of using a custom event where a controller sets a variable in the controller triggering the event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say we have an admin dashboard that you want to inject some code into using events so that you can decouple your plugins and not hard code dashboard functionality for particular plugins into the core admin dashboard.

**Create the firing of the event.**

> In APP/Controller/DashboardController

```
public function index()
{
    // Once this gets to the function triggered by this event, the "$this" in the parameters will be $event->subject(). Mentioned again below.
    $event = new Event('Controller.Dashboard.beforeDashboardIndex', $this)
    $this->eventManager()->dispatch($event);
    // your other index() code...
}
```

**Now create a listener that waits for that event to be triggered**

> A good place for this might be PluginName/src/Controller/Event/DashboardListener.php

```
namespace Plugin\Controller\Event;

use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;

class DashboardListener implements EventListenerInterface {

    public function implementedEvents() {
        return array(
            'Controller.Dashboard.beforeDashboardIndex' => 'myCustomMethod',
        );
    }

    public function myCustomMethod($event) {
        // $event->subject() = DashboardController();
        $event->subject()->set('dashboardAddon', 'me me me');
    }
}
```

**Finally turn the listener on. (ex. at the bottom of APP/config/bootstrap.php)**

> **Note**, this listener initialization can be anywhere that fires before DashboardController::index

```
// Attach event listeners
use Cake\Event\EventManager;
use PluginName\Controller\Event\DashboardListener;
$myPluginListener = new DashboardListener();
EventManager::instance()->on($myPluginListener);
```

Comment: have you got any solution for this issue  ?

Comment: Good explanation